# Assigning ng-model for dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a item in list with  with dropdown values as ROLES. I couldn't set ng-model for drop down .if I select Actor I wanted my ng-model to be set as Actor

```
<li class="dropdown" ng-model="$scope.Role">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">VIEW ROLE AS
 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>Actor</li>
          <li>Director</li>
   </li>
```

Comment: If it is a dropdown why are you using li's ...Why cant you use select and options

Comment: @Geeky It's a Bootstrap dropdown, not a normal HTML select.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'ng-model' only works on inputs and since the bootstrap dropdown is just a stylized list it has no real input. To get your example to work use 'ng-click' on the list elements to set 'Role'.

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">VIEW ROLE AS
<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li ng-click="setRole('Actor')">Actor</li>
      <li ng-click="setRole('Director')">Director</li>
```

And then somewhere in the controller create the 'setRole' function.

```
$scope.setRole = function (role) {
    $scope.Role = role;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Umer Z . Its really helpful